# Mysql 8 Slower than 5.7 on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-8.0

I am new to docker and I have recently been trying to setup my project on docker. I have successfully deployed the application on nginx and php and i have been successful in migrating th eDB also into a container. I have plans of moving from MySQL 5.7 to 8, but I noticed the select queries are much slower in MySQL 8.

Mysql 5.7

DockerFile

```
FROM mysql:5.7.29
CMD ["mysqld"]
EXPOSE 3306
```

docker compose:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  database:
    build:
        context: ./database
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
      - MYSQL_USER=username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /Path/to/data/folder:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-datavolume_five:
```

Mysql8

DockerFile

```
FROM mysql:8.0.18
CMD ["mysqld"]
EXPOSE 3306
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  database:
    build:
        context: ./database
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd
    command: ['--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /Path/to/database/folder:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

I have a sample query that that does a SELECT and I have tried it in several scenarios and it always turns out to be slow.
I had the query run 100 times in a loop and there was difference of 20 seconds.

Another attempt, I had the query run 100 times on unique id's and there was still anywhere between 15 -20 seconds difference(mysql 8 being slower).

I know that database query cache is not supported anymore but I am not sure if that makes a difference in the second scenario where the id's are unique.

sample query running in loop with 100 id's

```
"select * from booking_table where account_id = '" . $id . "' and status = 'booked' and checked_in = 1 and checked_out = 0 and type in ('type_a','type_b') and cancelled = 0 and end_date > '<end_date_time>'";
```

I need to know if there are certain default settings that I might be missing and if this is something to do with mysql config or docker config.

Comment: Convert the query to use bind parameter for `$id` and then compare performance. Also review the code that runs the query and ensure that statement caching is working. Check which engine is used for your table in both 5.7 and 8, is it the same e.g. InnoDB?

Comment: The engine is the same. It's InnoDb

Comment: I have made several changes to the mysql config including disabling the binary logging. still it is significantly slow.
[mysqld]

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2000M
symbolic-links=0
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
skip-log-bin  
ssl=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0

Comment: I updated to mysql 8.0.19, still no difference

Comment: Is the docker host a linux box?

Comment: I think you should do an EXPLAIN PLAN for the query on both instances of MySQL and see what's different between them.